# how to filter resources in dependency jar using maven?

Tags: java, spring, maven

I have a project named A， and there is a `spring-config.xml` and a `config.properties` in A. 　Project A dependency project B, and project B also have a resource file `spring-datasource.xml`.I want to filter resource during package project A ,so I use maven-resource-filter.But it can only filter the resource file in Project A, doesn't work for project B. How can i filter project B's resource file during package project A?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot (and should not) filter an already packaged dependency.
Filtering is enabled only during the build of the project.
More precisely, during the `process-resources` phase.

To achieve what you want, you have two ways :

- moving `spring-datasource.xml` in the `A` project

OR

- filtering `spring-datasource.xml` directly in the `B` project build.

Comment: but project B is a base jar, many projects will dependent on it . so I can not filer spring-datasource.xml directly in the B build. and move it to A looks inconvenient.

Comment: can I copy the file in project B to project A during building project A by some plugin?

Comment: If you do that the latter, you will finish with two `spring-datasource.xml` : one in the A jar and another in the B jar.